# Not able to mvn install and getting lombokprocessor error

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, lombok

I am trying to build a maven project. The same project is working on my other machine and now I am trying to setup this up on my colleagues machine. When I try to mvn clean install, I get the following error:

```
Compiling 683 source files to /Users/<Usename>/IdeaProjects/cards-gateway/target/classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.783 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-04-26T16:56:45+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project cards-gateway: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor (in unnamed module @0x3a846f28) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.processing to unnamed module @0x3a846f28 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project cards-gateway: Fatal error compiling
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:306)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:211)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:165)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:157)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:121)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:127)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:577)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Fatal error compiling
at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:796)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:129)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:301)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:211)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:165)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:157)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:121)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:127)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:577)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: o
```

Tried solutions:

- Tried changing the lombok version in pom.
- Tried replacing the m2 folder and repositories folder.
- Checked the java version vs lombok version vs maven version.
- Tried replacing the external dependency files and libraries.
- Tried running mvn clean install -X -U for forced lib download.
- Tried changing pom.xml and added dependencies for compiler plugin version and java version.

Please help resolve the error. Let me know if additional info is required: Java version is 1.8, maven version is 3.8.3 . Do I need to add any dependency or anything in the intellij

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.10</version>
        </dependency>
```

Pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>${java-version}</source>
                            <target>${java-version}</target>
                            <compilerArguments>
                                <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                            </compilerArguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
```

Comment: the error `because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.processing to unnamed module` clearly states that you are not on java 1.8. latest lombok versions (1.18.22 or 1.18.24) should resolve your issues, please check changelog: https://projectlombok.org/changelog

Comment: Also Upgrade the maven-compiler-plugin version...to most recent one..